# How to include spaces in filenames in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a line like this

```
file("c:/Program Files")
```

and I get the error

```
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 10: c:/Program Files
```

How do I include spaces in file names?

**UPDATE**

Here's the precise error and Gradle code.

Error:

```
* Where:
Script '.../gradle/tsp.gradle' line: 9

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 10: c:/Program Files
```

Code (the last line in this code is line 9, the remainder of the code is omitted):

```
/*
 * Code for Tom Sawyer Perspectives automation.
 */


project.ext {
    tspSearchPath = files(
        // For some Windows boxes, users may use this dir
        file("c:/Program Files"),
```

To be clear, I don't get the error when I run Gradle on Windows.  I get the error when I run Gradle on Mac.  I have a list of paths to search for all platforms and don't want to change the list on a per platform basis (although this is probably what I will do in the future after I learn more Gradle and Groovy).

However, there error is at the space and Mac supports spaces in file names.  Does Gradle's file method support spaces on Mac?  It does on Windows.  If it does on Mac, how do I include spaces in filenames?

Comment: Where exactly are you using this to get this error? Have you tried with a backslash instead of the slash?

Comment: Good question.  I have a list of paths to search for a third party framework that isn't available for automated download or installation.  I don't want to change the paths to search according to the operating system (although, that's probably a good idea).  Therefore, I actually got this error while running "gradlew" on my Mac.  I get that this is a Windows path and I don't need to search it on my Mac, but the quick and dirty solution is to have a list of paths for all platforms and search them all on all platforms.  As I learn Gradle, I imagine I'll learn a better way.  Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Using backslashs gave similar errors.

Comment: My question was more where/when exactly you get this error. From your description t's not clear if the `file` method above throws the error, or some other code that's being passed the file.

Comment: Cool, I updated the question with those details.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it on Gradle 1.8 and this code works perfectly fine:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
File x = file("C:/Program Files")
println x.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: This code does not run on a Mac.  Same error as I describe in the OP.  Even though "c:/Program Files" is a valid Mac OS/X path.  Note, without the "C:" part this code works on a Mac.

Comment: Why do you think this is a valid path on a Mac? I think what happens is that Gradle tries to canonicalize the path, which fails on a Mac.

Comment: @Jason - really? First you make us think its a question on the Windows platform and now you say its a Mac problem?  Why don't you add some detail to your question and be more specific?

Comment: I have similar problems. IMHO "C:" is a valid file (or directory) name on Mac, Linux, so this file would be in "C:" directory and called "Program Files"

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
new File("c:/Program Files")
```

This uses the Java File class instead of the Gradle DSL file method.